# Cocos2d scene switching and replacing issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a cocos2d box2d game with multiple levels.I'm simulating a smash effect with CCParticleSystem.I have a replay button on every level.The problem is that on my iPod touch(4 gen.) It crashes every time I press the replay button on a level.
My solution for replaying is the following:

```
CCMenuItemImage *replay = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"replaybutton.png" selectedImage:@"replaybutton_pushed.png" block:^(id){
NSLog(@"*** REPLAY BUTTON PRESSED ***");
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[[self class] node]]];
}];
```

The iOS simulator does it without crash but my real device not.
I can not debug , because Xcode does not recognize any error, like "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".
The only thing I could notice was an OpenGl error in the log:

```
OpenGL error 0x0501 in -[CCParticleSystemQuad postStep] 411
```

The same kind of crash happens also if I play on a level and go back to the main menu and switch to another level.

I would be really happy if anyone could help me. Even to find the source of the crash.

Comment: Do you have exception breakpoints enabled? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html. Also, make sure you run the game on the device in Debug mode connected to Xcode. If this still doesn't show you anything, then maybe iOS is closing your game because it runs out of memory. How much memory are you using? Watch out for any leaks or retain cycles.

Comment: Press continue on the debugger and see if it continues? I have this sometimes and it appears to be a recoverable error

Comment: Thank you.How can I track, if I'm running out of Memory. This is possible, because on iPhone 5 my app is running well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is with 
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[[self class] node]]];

especially in scene:[[self class] node]].

you see when we call replace scene, the existing scene is destroyed, which means that it gets dealloc-ated and all that. Now when you try to put back this dealloc-ated scene, you get a crash and since it is running as an animation, you can't even trace back it.

what you can do or at least try is to create a new instance of this scene and then call

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:newSceneInstanceOfTheSameClassYouJustCreated];
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: also you can enable zombies in Xcode to verify what I just said.